# How can I multiply words with numbers in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
print(df.words[0])
[('replacement', 1), ('shaver', 2)]

print(df.words[1])
[('filter', 2), ('purifier', 1), ('please', 2)]
```

I want to create a new column, called "all_words". The column, should represent the real strings, instead of numbers.

```
('head', 3) should be: "head,head,head"
```

**Desired Output from the example:**

```
print(df.all_words[0])
'replacement, shaver, shaver'


print(df.all_words[1])
'filter, filter, purifier, please, please'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to `apply` a function to join the tuples to a single string.

```
df['all_words'] = df.words.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(', '.join([y[0]] * y[1]) for y in x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `df.apply()`

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words' : [[('replacement', 1), ('shaver', 2)], [('filter', 2), ('purifier', 1), ('please', 2)]]})

def word_to_words(row):
    words_string = ''
    for tuple_set in row['words']:
        words_string += (tuple_set[0] + ', ') * tuple_set[1]
    return(words_string)

df['all_words'] = df.apply(word_to_words, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[[('filter', 2), ('purifier', 1), ('please', 2)]]], columns=['words'])
result = df.words.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(word for word, count in x for _ in range(count)))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0    filter, filter, purifier, please, please
Name: words, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simply solve thorug loop 
And its works..
If words is a list of multiple tuples

```
words = [[('replacement', 2), ('shaver', 2) ], [('filters', 2), ('purifier',1), ('plears', 3) ]]
Loop = words[0] #here you use indexing of words[0] or [1] both
Result = ()
for val in Loop:
    v = tuple([val[0] * 1 for _ in range(val[1])])
    Result = Result + v
Print(Result)
```